# Loading and storing a file at compile time with a type provider

Tags: ffi, compile-time, type-providers, idris

I'd like to load a (binary) file at compile time and store it in a toplevel variable of type [`Bytes`](https://github.com/ziman/idris-bytes):

```
module FileProvider

import Data.Bits
import Data.Bytes
import Data.Buffer

%default total

export
loadImage : String -> IO (Provider Bytes)
loadImage fileName = do
    Right file <- openFile fileName Read
      | Left err => pure (Error $ show err)
    Just buf <- newBuffer size
      | Nothing => pure (Error "allocation failed")
    readBufferFromFile file buf size
    Provide . dropPrefix 2 . pack <$> bufferData buf
  where
    size : Int
    size = 256 * 256 + 2
```

It seems to work correctly at runtime:

```
module Main

import FileProvider
import Data.Bits
import Data.Bytes

main : IO ()
main = do
     Provide mem <- loadImage "ram.mem"
       | Error err => putStrLn err
     printLn $ length mem
```

However, if I try to run it at compile time, it fails with a mysterious message mentioning FFI:

```
module Main

import FileProvider
import Data.Bits
import Data.Bytes

%language TypeProviders
%provide (mem : Bytes) with loadImage "ram.mem"

main : IO ()
main = do
     printLn $ length mem
```

> ```
> $ idris -p bytes -o SOMain SOMain.idr 
> Symbol "idris_newBuffer" not found
> idris: user error (Could not call foreign function "idris_newBuffer" with args [65538])
> ```

What is going on here and how can I load a file's contents at compile time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`idris_newbuffer` is a C function used by `Data.Buffer`. From the [docs to type providers](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/guides/type-providers-ffi.html#in-the-interpreter):

> If we want to call our foreign functions from interpreted code (such as the REPL or a type provider), we need to dynamically link a library containing the symbols we need.

So every function that uses FFI needs to have a dynamic library linked. That'd be `Data.Buffer` and `Data.ByteArray`. Lets focus on the first and see what problems arise:

So `Data.Buffer` needs `%dynamic "idris_buffer.so"` (and not only the `%include C "idris_buffer.h"` it currently has). You can copy `idris/rts/idris_buffer.(h|c)` and remove the function that needs the other rts-stuff. To compile a shared library run:

```
cc -o idris_buffer.so -fPIC -shared idris_buffer.c
```

With a modified `Data.Buffer` to use it, you'd still get an error:

```
Could not use <<handle {handle: ram.mem}>> as FFI arg.
```

The FFI call is in [`Data.Buffer.readBufferFromFile`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/aae637d43971d089bfc34ab532b8ba4c396aaaea/libs/base/Data/Buffer.idr#L131%60). The `File` argument causes trouble. That's because Idris sees that `openFile` is used (another C function) and 
[transforms it in a Haskell call](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/33d367de25645ae87357cd712d3be363477c0437/src/Idris/Core/Execute.hs#L344). On the one hand that's nice, because during compilation we're interpreting Idris code, and that make following functions like `readLine` C/JS/Node/… agnostic. But in this case it's unfortunate, because the Haskell backend doesn't support the [returned file handle for FFI calls](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/33d367de25645ae87357cd712d3be363477c0437/src/Idris/Core/Execute.hs#L642). So we can write another `fopen : String -> String -> IO Ptr` function that does the same thing but has another name so the `Ptr` will stay `Ptr`, as those can be used in FFI calls.

With this done, there is is another error thanks to built-ins:

```
Could not use prim__registerPtr (<<ptr 0x00000000009e2bf0>>) (65546) as FFI arg.
```

`Data.Buffer` uses `ManagedPtr` in its backend. And yep, that's unsupported in FFI calls also. So you'd need to change these to `Ptr`. Both of these *could* get supported in the compiler, I guess.

Finally everything should work for a valid `%provide (mem : Buffer)`. But, nope, because:

```
Can't convert pointers back to TT after execution.
```

Even though Idris can now read a file in compilation time, it can't make `Buffer` or anything else with a `Pnt` accessible to runtime  - and that's quite reasonable. Having just a pointer from when the program was compiled is just a random thing at run time. So you either need to transform the data to the result in the provider or use an intermediate format like `Provider (List Bits8)`.

[I made a short example](https://github.com/Xashili/idris_read_bytes_ct) to have the `List Bits8` accessible in `main`. `Buffer` is basically `Data.Buffer` with `_openFile` included and `Pnt` instead of `ManagedPtr`. I hope this helps you somehow, but maybe some of the compiler people can give more background.